# INSERT to a table with only one serial-column doesn't actually insert anything

Tags: postgresql, insert, psycopg2

I have a postgres database with the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE stocks 
    (
       id serial PRIMARY KEY
    );
```

and another table that is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE stock_attributes 
    (
       id serial PRIMARY KEY,
       market_id TEXT,
       short_name TEXT,
       full_name TEXT,
       isin TEXT,
       stock_id serial REFERENCES stocks(id)
    );
```

This is my attempt at normalizing, so forgive me if It's wrong but, I'm trying to insert a new row into `stocks` table and then use the id on another insert into the 2nd table:

```
INSERT INTO stocks DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING id;
```

The query goes through, and it returns a new id, but when I run the 2nd query into the stock_attributes table, I get an error that relation id doesn't exist on stocks table.

```
INSERT INTO stock_attributes AS a (market_id, short_name, full_name, isin, stock_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s);
```

This one fails with

```
insert or update on table "stock_attributes" violates foreign key constraint "stock_attributes_stock_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (stock_id)=(3) is not present in table "stocks".
```

I'm using psycopg2 with python.

Here is the code, pretty much copied from postgres python guides:

```
def execute(sql,args):
    conn = None
    try:
        # read database configuration
        params = config()
        # connect to the PostgreSQL database
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        # create a new cursor
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql, args)
        conn.commit()
        # close communication with the database
        cur.close()
        print("SQL executed")
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()

def execute_and_return(sql, args):
    """ insert a new vendor into the vendors table """
    conn = None
    rows = None
    try:
        # read database configuration
        params = config()
        # connect to the PostgreSQL database
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        # create a new cursor
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql, args)
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        # close communication with the database
        cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
    return rows
```

Comment: This should work. Maybe someone can spot the error in your code if you show some of it.

Comment: It seems that you are using different cursors for each query. This can lead to an attempt to perform modification in 2 different transactions without commit.  i.e. stocks table is modified in transaction 1 (And it still pending a commit), and stock_attributes entry is created in transaction 2. While transaction 1 is not committed yet, there is no created data in stocks table.

Comment: @IlyaDyoshin Ah, I see. How can I use the same cursor for two queries then?

Comment: Never mind, I tried asking for chewed food without thinking it through myself. I declared the cursor "globally" at the top of the file and removed creating of it from the functions, and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your key reference to the `stocks` tables is incorrect. You have:

```
stock_id serial REFERENCES stocks(id)
```

when it should be:

```
 stock_id integer REFERENCES stocks(id)
```

Serial creates a sequences of type `integer` and sets the column type to `integer` with a default value of `nextval("<generated sequence name>")`. If you change the type from `serial` to `integer` on the foreign key, it should work.